# Loading modules from assemblies with ninject 3 and MVC 3 (.dll)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I was working on a project that was using ninject 2.2 so i converted to ninject 3.0 and now it seem that this code doesn't work anymore.

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Load("PFFTester.Persistence.dll");   
    kernel.Load("Pyrosphere.Providers.dll");       
}
```

I have ninject modules in those two dlls.. however i do not wish to search all the assemblies.. since i know they are located in thoses.. this worked before! I get no errors except when i start MVC 3 which try to load a controller but doesn't inject anything so it crash saying couldnt find a constructor without parameters.. so what wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Be sure that MVC 3 project reference the Ninject.MVC3 dll ! and it will work.